# Open XLS file in protected mode manually

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to open the excel document in protected mode manually.

I know one way to open it as a protected mode.

Uploading to the web and Downloading it back let Excel think it's unsafe so that it opened in protected mode.

However, the solution above is too pain.

Answer (score 0):

Opening excel with a command line with option solve it!!

excel.exe /s "ABSOLTE PATH OF EXCEL FILE.XLS"

Comment: With Excel 2019 the switch is `\r`. Unfortunately, file opens as _read only_, not in _protected mode_.